# Does Ohm's law apply to a charge moving through empty space?

Tags: charge, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, vacuum

**Clarification:** I was playing with this idea and I thought of a scenario in which made me think Ohm's law might be incomplete. I will try to be as straightforward as possible. **I am asking if the Ohm's law is consistent or not**

Let me make my concepts in these ideas clear so there is no confirmation regarding their definition.
*Voltage:* The engery (to go from one point to another) per charge

*Current:* The number of charges that pass through a specific point in 1 second

---->
Now consider a charge moving through empty space. It's current is 1 ampere (it passes through a point in 1 second completely) and it has some definite energy (voltage≠0)
According to Ohm's law

V=IR

V=1(0)

V=0 but V≠0

So does Ohm's law apply to a charge moving through empty space?

Comment: Ohm's law, like most things in physics, has situations it applies to. And single charges moving in an electric field in vacuum are not among those situations.

Comment: So it would be incomplete then because it's not consistent?

Comment: If you consider U.S. law incomplete because it doesn't apply in Canada or on Mars, then yes, you could as well call Ohm's law incomplete because of the above. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: How did you determine that the current is 1 A, and between what two points are you computing the voltage?

Comment: Ohm's law applies only to current in a conductor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Voting to re-open. The question is perfectly clear. The OP is asking why Ohm's law appears not to apply in the scenario they are describing. There are various possible *answers*, as outlined in the above comments, but the *question* itself is completely clear.

Comment: The question (in its current form after edits) is answered by the first sentence of the Wikipedia article on Ohm's law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law What's the point of reopening?

Comment: @kricheli Because the reason given for closing the question is incorrect, and "the answer is in Wikipedia" or "I think the answer is really obvious" are not valid reasons for closing a question.

Comment: Also, in addition to @kricheli 's first comment: Ohm's law is proven in almost any electromagnetism textbook. Read the proof and check whether it can be applied to the situation in the question (spoiler: it can't). So the fault lies in the logic, not in the theorem.

Comment: @gandalf61 "insufficient prior research" was once-upon-a-time a valid reason for closing a question. I guess SE has now decided it will try to replicate all the information in Wikipedia (and other sources) rather than defer basic questions to encyclopedic sources, but many old-timers might still expect posters to check those sources before asking such questions.

Comment: Thanks @gandalf61 for reopening the question. I now know Ohm's law doesn't apply to that situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The historic formulation of Ohm's law usually starts as something like,

> In a metallic conductor, ...

Today, we might say "in an ideal conductor...", but the restriction remains: Ohm's law is a description of certain conductive materials, not a universal truth. (Another way of looking at it is as a definition of which materials are ideal conductors, aka "Ohmic" conductors)

Ohm's law doesn't apply to semiconductor junctions, to devices with significant inductance, to thin structures that admit quantum tunnelling, etc. It also doesn't apply to electrons in vacuum, but that shouldn't be surprising given all the other situations it doesn't apply to.